# Extra Dot for Css Dotted Underline

Tags: html, css, dotted-line

There is an extra dot (thicker) at the end of a word and sometimes at the beginning.  Also, is it possible to make the dots round?

[image]
'

CODE

```
<span style="border-bottom: 3px dotted #111;">Personal Project
Magazine Ads
Personal Project
Magazine Ads
Packaging 
Logo Design
Corporate Identity</span>
```

Comment: This link could be helpful to you https://medium.com/@luclemo/creating-true-dotted-borders-with-css-233f296d8145#.ang9htore

Answer (score 1):

The spacing of the dots are not defined by the specification and are implementation-specific. The radius of the dots is half the calculated border-bottom-width.

So if you want the exact shape displaying in border, you can try the property `border-image` of css3. You can reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) on mdn.